# Why only Column Heading is displayed not Column data (Is Logic of Mv vM wrong ?)

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, model-binding

I am beginnerof silverlight application using c# and xaml. **What i am trying to do is to display information like:**

```
SerialNumber  FirstName LastName //These are headings and below is the data
s0             ss1       ss1L
s1             ss2       ss2L
```

where     `s0             ss1       ss1L`  and     s`1             ss2       ss2L` must be `List`.

What My problem is :

It just show the headings but not data below like this: http://prntscr.com/3axadr But show nothing below the headings.

My code is below :

My Project Name is `DEV_CENTER` and `MainPage.Xaml` is

```
<UserControl x:Class="DEV_CENTER.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
              xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DEV_CENTER"
             xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:ProgramViewModel x:Key="ProgramViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <data:DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="gridPrograms" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ssss1 }" IsReadOnly="True"  DataContext="{StaticResource ProgramViewModel}" >
            <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="SerialNumber" Binding="{Binding Path=sss1}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Path=sss2}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding Path=sss3}" Width="3*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
            </data:DataGrid.Columns>
        </data:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

You can use all code to test. Could some one please tell me why it don't show `" s0             ss1       ss1L"` and  `s1             ss2       ss2L` ? Is there anything wrong in Mvvm logic ? or anything else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bindings are all wrong - you're binding to weird property names. Is this actually the case in your code or did it get messed up when you were writing the question?

Anyway, your grid should look like this:

```
<data:DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="gridPrograms" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Programs}" IsReadOnly="True"  DataContext="{StaticResource ProgramViewModel}" >
    <data:DataGrid.Columns>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="SerialNumber" Binding="{Binding Path=SerialNumber}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" Width="3*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
    </data:DataGrid.Columns>
</data:DataGrid>
```

Also, it's always good to have a look at Visual Studio's output window when debugging - it may contain helpful binding error messages which will allow you to understand why your xaml doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: there is a quiet strange problem : As i try to change "ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ssss1}" to "ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Programs}" and as i save it. visual studio crashes and i need to restart. And it is not able to change it. (but it has saved the changes of Binding="{Binding Path=SerialNumber}" and 2 similar other) but not able to save  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Programs}"  ANY IDEA WHY ?

Comment: it gives the window like this http://prntscr.com/3ay6jj  And then VStudio closes.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that

Comment: Ok ,I mark it as answer but still i have not tested because of VStudio crash problem on replacing thge previous part to "ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Programs}". This crash is quiet strange.